# Remove web middleware in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I know `web` middleware group is assigned to every route now. But can someone tell me how to remove if for specefic route? I tried:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('web',['except'=>[
            'index',
        ]]);

    }
}
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web middleware is now applied to all routes in routes.php. This happens in the RouteServiceProvider map function.

If you have an api for example which should not use web middleware you can go with something like this

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);
    $this->mapApiRoutes($router);
}

protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}

protected function mapApiRoutes(Router $router) 
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-api.php');
    });
}
```

Now every route in routes.php has web middleware and everything in routes-api.php the api middleware

Comment: What do you mean by modify original code? your routes.php also exists in a fresh setup and you add stuff. It is now meant to be done this way. The idea behind is that most stuff goes in web middleware anyway and it's ugly to have this group in your routes.php by default. It's nothing different from adding new controllers, routes, providers, migrations etc.

Comment: yes, you're right. But I think maybe there should be a method to let people determine to remove default middleware for routes.